# allow only .25, .50 and .75 in a text box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a web application and using javascript to restrict or round off a value. Whenever I enter any decimal value in a textbox, it should be rounded off to .25, .50, .75, or .00. any idea how to do that? Even if am able to enter only .25, .50, .75 and .00 is also fine... but how to restrict for only these specific values?

Comment: Is this about Java or JavaScript? The two are unrelated.

Comment: Considering he has added jquery my guess would be JavaScript.

Comment: I'm interested in seeing if anyone has an elegant solution for this, but you can always extract the decimals and use if's. It's not pretty, but since you have few options it's actually likely to be the most performant. Not maintainable though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case it's not obvious from Jon Taylors answer, the appropriate way of using if statements to solve this is the following:

```
var floorValue = Math.floor(value);
var remainder = value - floorValue;
if (remainder < 0.325) {
    if (remainder < 0.125) {
        newValue = floorValue;
    } else {
        newValue = floorValue + 0.25;
    }
} else {
    if (remainder < 0.625) {
        newValue = floorValue + 0.5;
    } else if (remainder < 0.875) {
        newValue = floorValue + 0.75;
    } else {
        newValue = floorValue + 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The jQuery UI spinner has this functionality built in.

http://btburnett.com/spinner/example/example.html

OR

http://www.htmldrive.net/items/demo/541/jQuery-UI-Spinner-numeric-stepper

Answer (score 4):

Or:

```
var n = $('#myInput').val();
alert(.25 * Math.round( 4 * n));
```

Comment: Elegant. I like it. A very good solution for this, but a shame I can't use it for limiting to numbers divisible by 0.2 (there are rounding issues giving values like 0.80000001).

Comment: @Thor84no Hi, I've not correctly tested because I'm limited by Ipad resource, but could be: (Math.round( 5 * n ) / 5), the above script is not mine, I see it on a univ. course, but is beauty and I fixed it in my mind ;-)

Comment: @AlexBall Yes, for some reason `* .2` has rounding errors while `/ 5` is fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You just need an if statement

For example, lets assume instead that you were trying to round to the nearest whole number you would do the following or something similar:

```
var remainder = value - Math.floor(value);
if(remainder < 0.5)
    newValue = Math.floor(value);
else
    newValue = Math.floor(value) + 1;
```

There however are many many ways of doing this, you just need to pick the appropriate numbers instead of 0.5 and may need to check several ranges.

I am in no way saying this is the best option but this should give you an idea.

As for the textbox entry you can run this every keyup/keydown etc and replace the value with your `newValue`

Comment: At least store `Math.floor(value)` in a var if it's going to be used that many times (he needs 4 if/elses).

Comment: As I said this was just an example, as to the sort of thinking he needed to go about doing it.  It is not meant to be any sort of optimized solution nor indeed a solution to his exact problem, that is for him to figure out.

Comment: Yeah, it wasn't really a criticism as much as a note to complement the answer. Apologies if that wasn't clear.

Comment: Na thats fair enough :) just think SO is far too full of people who give answers out that just get copied and pasted in.  I prefer to give answers that make the OP think, while still giving them an indication as to what direction they should be headed.  As a result though most of my answers don;t get accepted haha, people prefer copy/paste.

Answer (score 1):

```
var decimal = n - Math.floor(n)
decimal=decimal*100;
var factor = Math.round(decimal/25)
decimal  = n + 0.25*factor;
```